# How do I replace multiple occurrence of a character between specified strings using vi or sed?

Tags: awk, sed, replace, between

I'm trying to replace "," only when it occurs between 65510 and "i":

```
2001::/32,fd00::230:5,0,100,0,65510,6939,i

2001:200:900::/40,fd00::230:5,0,100,0,65510,6939,2516,7660,7660,7660,i
```

So the desired output is:

```
2001::/32,fd00::230:5,0,100,0,65510_6939,i

2001:200:900::/40,fd00::230:5,0,100,0,65510_6939_2516_7660_7660_7660,i
```

I've tried the following:

```
sed -e 's/,\([^65510]*\)i/_\1i/' input-file.txt
```

But the output only replace the last ",":

```
2001::/32,fd00::230:5,0,100,0,65510,6939_i

2001:200:900::/40,fd00::230:5,0,100,0,65510,6939,2516,7660,7660,7660_i
```

Comment: You should include some non-trivial cases in your sample input/output including `,165510,foo,i`, `,655101,foo,i`, `,65510,foo,65510,bar,i`, and `foo,65510,i` as it's always easy to match the string you want but much harder to not match strings you don't want! All currently posted solutions will fail given some of those inputs (and probably others I haven't mentioned).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `sed` you can use a loop:

```
[STEP 101] $ cat file
2001::/32,fd00::230:5,0,100,0,65510,6939,i
2001:200:900::/40,fd00::230:5,0,100,0,65510,6939,2516,7660,7660,7660,i
[STEP 102] $
[STEP 103] $ sed -e :loop -e 's/\(,65510.*\),\(.*,i\)/\1_\2/; tloop' file
2001::/32,fd00::230:5,0,100,0,65510_6939,i
2001:200:900::/40,fd00::230:5,0,100,0,65510_6939_2516_7660_7660_7660,i
[STEP 104] $
[STEP 105] $ # if your sed supports -E it can be a bit simpler --
[STEP 106] $ sed -E -e :loop -e 's/(,65510.*),(.*,i)/\1_\2/; tloop' file
2001::/32,fd00::230:5,0,100,0,65510_6939,i
2001:200:900::/40,fd00::230:5,0,100,0,65510_6939_2516_7660_7660_7660,i
```

About the `t` command:

> `t`*`label`*
>
> > If a `s///` has done a successful substitution since the last input line was read and since the last `t` or `T`
> > command, then branch to *label*; if *label* is omitted, branch to end of script.

---

You can use the cool sed debug tool [sedsed](https://github.com/aureliojargas/sedsed) to see how it works:

[image: sedsed]

Comment: That would fail if 65510 was present as part of a different string, e.g. `165510`. I know the OP didn't make it clear but their code starts with `/,65510...` so I suspect thats what they **really** want to match. Also note that it's undesirably replace the `,` before `i` with `_` in the output.

Comment: This is the closest one that solves my problem using 'sed'. 
I can clean up "_i" easily with ",i" from this point on. 
Thanks so much.

Comment: Ed, good point.
But in my case, "65510" is always true. 
So, ",65510," always appears throughout the file. 
pynexj's solution works very well for my purpose. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples in GNU `awk`.

```
awk '
match($0,/65510.*i/){
  val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  gsub(/,/,"_",val)
  print substr($0,1,RSTART-1) val substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
}
' Input_file
```

***More Generic answer:*** In case we have more than one occurrences of `i` and it may or may not come in in series like `65510....i....i` then one could try following.

```
awk '
{
  line=""
  while(match($0,/65510[^i]*/)){
    val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH+1)
    gsub(/,/,"_",val)
    line=(line?line:"")substr($0,1,RSTART-1) val
    $0=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH+1)
  }
  if($0!=""){
    line=line $0
  }
  print line
}
'  Input_file
```

Comment: That would fail if 65510 was present as part of a different string, e.g. `165510`. I know the OP didn't make it clear but their code starts with `/,65510...` so I suspect thats what they **really** want to match. It'll also undesirably replace the `,` before `i` with `_` in the output.

Comment: @EdMorton, sure, thank you for your input sir. I have considered 1 case, didn't considered this corner case. That's why I usually write line, as per shown samples. I will try to cover this point after I finish my cooking and dinner sir, take care.

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E '/\b65510\b.*i/{:a;s/\b(65510\b[^,i]*),([^i])/\1_\2/;ta}' file
```

If the current line contains `65510` and then `i`, replace any `,`'s between them by `_`'s.

Comment: @EdMorton thanks, amended the solution to take in your concerns, I actually misread the `,i` part confusing the `tried` with `desired`. As always, what the OP specifies and expects may differ and so I always qualify my solutions with the word **might**.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU awk for the 3rd arg to match() and gensub():

```
$ awk 'match($0,/(.*,)(65510.*)(,i.*)/,a){$0=a[1] gensub(/,/,"_","g",a[2]) a[3]} 1' file
2001::/32,fd00::230:5,0,100,0,65510_6939,i

2001:200:900::/40,fd00::230:5,0,100,0,65510_6939_2516_7660_7660_7660,i
```

The above just separates each input line into 3 parts (the part til the comma before `65510`, the part from `65510` til the character before the comma before `i`, and the rest of the line) then replaces every `,` with `_` in that middle part and pastes the 3 parts back together to form the modified output line. If the input line doesn't contain `,65510.*,i` then it's left as-is.

It will fail if `,65510x,.*,i` (where `x` is any char that is not a comma) can exist in your input - if that can happen then include it in the example in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Perl

```
$ cat lou.txt
2001::/32,fd00::230:5,0,100,0,65510,6939,i
2001:200:900::/40,fd00::230:5,0,100,0,65510,6939,2516,7660,7660,7660,i
$ perl -pe ' s/65510\K(.+?)(?=,i)/$c=$1;$c=~s!,!_!g;$c/ge ' lou.txt
2001::/32,fd00::230:5,0,100,0,65510_6939,i
2001:200:900::/40,fd00::230:5,0,100,0,65510_6939_2516_7660_7660_7660,i
$
```

or

```
$ perl -pe ' s/(?=65510)(.+?)(?=,i)/$c=$1;$c=~s!,!_!g;$c/ge ' lou.txt
2001::/32,fd00::230:5,0,100,0,65510_6939,i
2001:200:900::/40,fd00::230:5,0,100,0,65510_6939_2516_7660_7660_7660,i
$
```

If you are sure that there will always be a comma before 65510, then

```
$ perl -pe ' s/,(?=65510)(.+?)(?=,i)/$c=$1;$c=~s!,!_!g;sprintf(",%s",$c)/ge ' lou.txt
2001::/32,fd00::230:5,0,100,0,65510_6939,i
2001:200:900::/40,fd00::230:5,0,100,0,65510_6939_2516_7660_7660_7660,i
$
```

If 65510 is wrapped both sides by comma, then

```
$ perl -pe ' s/,(?=65510,)(.+?)(?=,i)/$c=$1;$c=~s!,!_!g;sprintf(",%s",$c)/ge ' lou.txt
2001::/32,fd00::230:5,0,100,0,65510_6939,i
2001:200:900::/40,fd00::230:5,0,100,0,65510_6939_2516_7660_7660_7660,i
$
```